# Using loops in python to configure credit card number

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working on this project in which I have to check if a credit card number is valid or not. In this case I only need an 8 digit credit card(I know that's not reality). Here is the question

The last digit of a credit card number is the check digit, which protects against transcription errors such as an error in a single digit or switching two digits. The following method is used to verify actual credit card numbers but, for simplicity, we will describe it for numbers with 8 digits instead of 16:

> • Starting from the rightmost digit, form the sum of every other
>   digit. For example, if the credit card number is `4358 9795`, then you
>   form the sum `5 + 7 + 8 + 3 = 23.`
>
> • Double each of the digits that were not included in the preceding
>   step. Add all digits of the resulting numbers. For example, with the
>   number given above, doubling the digits, starting with the
>   next-to-last one, `yields 18 18 10 8`. Adding all digits in these values
>   yields `1 + 8 + 1 + 8 + 1 + 0 + 8 = 27`.
>
> • Add the sums of the two preceding steps. If the last digit of the
>   result is 0, the number is valid. In our case, 23 + 27 = 50, so the
>   number is valid.

Write a program that implements this algorithm. The user should supply an 8-digit number, and you should print out whether the number is valid or not. If it is not valid, you should print the value of the check digit that would make it valid.

I have to use loops to do the sum. However, I do not know how to use loops for that.

Here's my code

```
# Credit Card Number Check. The last digit of a credit card number is the check digit,
# which protects against transcription errors such as an error in a single digit or
# switching two digits. The following method is used to verify actual credit card
# numbers but, for simplicity, we will describe it for numbers with 8 digits instead
# of 16:
#     Starting from the rightmost digit, form the sum of every other digit. For
#     example, if the credit card number is 43589795, then you form the sum
#     5 + 7 + 8 + 3 = 23.
#    Double each of the digits that were not included in the preceding step. Add #    all
#     digits of the resulting numbers. For example, with the number given above,
#     doubling the digits, starting with the next-to-last one, yields 18 18 10 8. Adding
#     all digits in these values yields 1 + 8 + 1 + 8 + 1 + 0 + 8 = 27.
#     Add the sums of the two preceding steps. If the last digit of the result is 0, the
#     number is valid. In our case, 23 + 27 = 50, so the number is valid.
# Write a program that implements this algorithm. The user should supply an 8-digit
# number, and you should print out whether the number is valid or not. If it is not
# valid, you should print out the value of the check digit that would make the number
# valid.

    card_number = int(input("8-digit credit card number: "))

rights = 0
for i in card_number[1::2]:
   rights += int(i)

lefts = 0
for i in card_number[::2]:
   lefts += int(i)*2%10+int(i)*2/10

print card_number, (rights +lefts)/10

if remaining == 0:
    print("Card number is valid")

else:
    print("Card number is invalid")

    if digit_7 - remaining < 0:
        checkDigit = int(digit_7 + (10 - remaining))
        print("Check digit should have been:", checkDigit)

    else:
        checkDigit = int(digit_7 - remaining)
        print("Check digit should have been:", checkDigit)
```

Comment: What are your errors?

Comment: There are no errors, I need to use loops for this program and do not know how. This program works, but it hasn't taken account of the sum of alternate numbers and their doubles. The last digit of the total sum needs to be o. Check digit is 4.

Comment: What is your question? It is unclear what specifically you're trying to get help on. Please edit/update your question to ask a specific question.

Comment: Dan, here is the question in simple terms. We need to check an 8 digit credit card number of its validity. The conditions are:-

1. The last digit/check digit must be 4.

2. Starting from the rightmost digit, form the sum of every other digit. For example, if the credit card number is 4358 9795, then you form the sum 5 + 7 + 8 + 3 = 23. Now take all the numbers which were left, and double them. The sum of the first group of numbers and 2nd group of numbers should be divisible by 10./or have last digit as 0.

Comment: Yes, but what problem are you having doing this?

Comment: I need to use loops instead of just using simple addition and if else statements

Comment: I am getting syntax errors as well now.

Comment: @JoshShroeder, does my final answer work for you? If yes, you can select my answer like a "accepted answer".

Comment: Jmillian, it is not checking the card number properly and not giving the correct check digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another possible solution:

```
cc_number = input("8-digit credit card number: ").replace(" ", "")
total1 = 0
total2 = 0

for digit in cc_number[-1::-2]:
    total1 += int(digit)

for digit in cc_number[-2::-2]:
    total2 += sum(int(x) for x in str(int(digit)*2))

remainder = (total1 + total2) % 10

if remainder == 0:
    print("Card is valid!")
else:
    invalid_check_digit = int(cc_number[-1])

    if invalid_check_digit - remainder < 0:
        valid_check_digit = invalid_check_digit + (10 - remainder)
    else:
        valid_check_digit = invalid_check_digit - remainder

    print("Card is invalid - the correct check digit is {}".format(valid_check_digit))
```

Giving you the following output:

```
8-digit credit card number: 4358 9795
Card is valid!
```

Or:

```
8-digit credit card number: 4358 9794
Card is invalid - the correct check digit is 5
```

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for the answer. How would we find the correct check digit if the card number is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
cards = ["43589795"]
for card_number in cards:  
     rights = sum(map(int, card_number[1::2]))
     lefts = sum(map(lambda x: int(x)*2%10+int(x)*2/10, card_number[::2])) # sum of doubled values
     print card_number, (rights +lefts)/10
```

Same solution without map and lambda magic:

```
rights = 0
for i in card_number[1::2]:
   rights += int(i)

lefts = 0
for i in card_number[::2]:
   lefts += int(i)*2%10+int(i)*2/10

print card_number, (rights +lefts)/10
```

And full answer on your question:

```
card_number = str(raw_input("8-digit credit card number: ")).replace(" ", "")

rights = 0
for i in card_number[1::2]:
   rights += int(i)

lefts = 0
for i in card_number[::2]:
   lefts += int(i)*2%10+int(i)*2/10

remaining = (rights +lefts)%10

digit_7 = int(card_number[-1]) # Last digit

if remaining == 0:
    print("Card number is valid")

else:
    print("Card number is invalid")

    if digit_7 - remaining < 0:
        checkDigit = int(digit_7 + (10 - remaining))
        print("Check digit should have been:", checkDigit)

    else:
        checkDigit = int(digit_7 - remaining)
        print("Check digit should have been:", checkDigit)
```

Comment: Yes I am! Can you please improvise this in my code? I will really appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean? It's exactly your algorithm. But instead of `number`, I'm using array of numbers - cards. Map it's a `for loop`.

Comment: Well there is one issue here. We are not supposed to use arrays yet. So technically we can use for and while loops but not the def statement or arrays.

Comment: Ok, @JoshShroeder, I created a version without arrays. But with iteration through string symbols. I hope it's ok for you :) Because it's impossible to iterate without iterable object (string or array/tuple).

Comment: @Jmillian can you please review the edits and correct my code?

Comment: @JoshShroeder, I updated my answer. Probably, it's not right to edit your question. And it will be better, if you revert it for previous state.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
d1=np.transpose(np.array(list('43589795'), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((4,2)))[0]*2
d2=np.transpose(np.array(list('43589795'), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((4,2)))[1]
if (np.sum(np.hstack([list(entry) for entry in d1.astype(str)]).astype(np.uint8))+np.sum(d2))%10==0:
    return "Validated"
```

In the example case, we get 50 which is validated.

Answer (score 0):

Prune all spaces from the credit card number and try the following code:

```
import itertools
sum = 0
for multiplicand,didgit in zip(itertools.cycle([2,1]), str(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER)):
    result = multiplicand * int(didgit)
    sum += result / 10
    sum += result % 10
print "valid" if sum % 10 == 0 else "invalid"
```

The above code loops through the credit card number and computes both sums simultainously.