# Selecting alternative numbers using loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do you select every other number using loops? Lets say we have a sequence of 8 digits, `12345678` How do we select alternate numbers starting from the right and add them? Therefore we would have to add 8 + 6 + 4 + 2.

Comment: addition doesnt care about order ... you get the same answer regardless of order

Comment: Why are you adding `2` twice and skipping `4`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, my bad. I corrected it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do get more control over loop increments in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930404/how-do-get-more-control-over-loop-increments-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

`reduce(sum,a[-1::-2])` explain to teacher that under the hood both filter and sum are loops

see also the following

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

in answer to your other question

```
def isvalid(c):
  return not (sum(c[-1::-2])+sum(map(int,"".join(map(str,(2*x for x in c[-2::-2] ))))))%10

def get_cc_num():
   while True:
       try: return map(int,raw_input("enter 8 digit number"))
       except ValueError:print "Invalid number"


print isvalid(get_cc_num())
```

Comment: Thank you. How would we write it as the addition of alternate numbers? why did we use -1 and -2?

Comment: it means start at the end (a[-1]) and go to the begining, and each time step -2 places

Comment: Thank You. This is part of the original problem I am working on here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658339/using-loops-in-python-to-configure-credit-card-number

Would you please take a look at my code and help?

Comment: there is an answer to your other question now as well

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry we aren't supposed to use def and return statements as we havent gone through them yet. Only for and while loops. Sorry for being a pain but I have been trying to do this code since 9 this morning before posting it here 4 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Use python's built in [range([start], stop [, step])](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) method.

You can iterate backwards from 8 to 1 in steps of `-2` like this:

```
total=sum(range(8, 0, -2))
```

Or forward from 1 to 8 in steps of 2 like this:

```
total=sum(range(2, 9, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you, and just for knowledge, why did we enter 8, 0, -2 inside the bracket?Very new to Python but developing a love for it

Comment: @JoshShroeder Those are the start, end, and stepping parameters for the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([int(x) for i, x in enumerate(reversed('12345678')) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Can you express it using a for loop please?